# XSLT escape escaped text

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I'm new at xslt. And don't understand how to prevent escaping escaped text in inputs, because internal parser sent already escaped html.

For example, I input a string of non ISO-8859-1 encoding such as "čč". Internal parser escape it to &#269 ;&#269 ; and sent to xsl as &#269 ;&#269 ; But xslt parser convert to &amp ;#269 ;&amp ;#269 ; And finally at page I can see &#269 ;&#269 ;, but I want čč.

Please help me:)

Xslt code for creating textfield, ../../../Values/TextFieldValue[TextField/textFieldID = $textFieldID]/value it is already escaped text, which xslt parser escape again.

```
       <xsl:call-template name="createTextField">
            <xsl:with-param name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="'q'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../queryID"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'_field'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="textFieldID"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="title" select="label"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="../../../Values/TextFieldValue[TextField/textFieldID = $textFieldID]/value"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="requestparameters" select="../../../../requestparameters"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="size" select="$size"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="class" select="$class"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Xslt template which used:

```
<xsl:template name="createTextField">
    <xsl:param name="id" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="name" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="type" select="'text'"/>
    <xsl:param name="class" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="disabled" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxlength" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="readonly" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="title" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="placeholder" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="element" select="null"/>
    <xsl:param name="size" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="min" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="max" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="width" select="'99%'"/>
    <xsl:param name="requestparameters" select="requestparameters"/>

    <input type="{$type}">

        <xsl:if test="$id">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$id"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$name">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$name"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$class">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="$class"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$disabled != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="disabled">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$maxlength">
            <xsl:attribute name="maxlength">
                <xsl:value-of select="$maxlength"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$readonly">
            <xsl:attribute name="readonly">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/> 
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>           

        <xsl:if test="$size != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="size">
                <xsl:value-of select="$size"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$size = '' and $width != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>width: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$width"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$type = 'number' and $min != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="min">
                <xsl:value-of select="$min"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$type = 'number' and $max != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="max">
                <xsl:value-of select="$max"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($disabled) and $requestparameters">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$requestparameters/parameter[name=$name]/value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$element/*[name()=$name]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$element/*[name()=$name]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:if test="$title != ''">            
            <xsl:attribute name="title" >
                <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$placeholder">
            <xsl:attribute name="placeholder" >
                <xsl:value-of select="$placeholder"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

    </input>        
</xsl:template>
```

This is solution doesn't work

```
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($disabled) and $requestparameters">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$requestparameters/parameter[name=$name]/value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$element/*[name()=$name]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$element/*[name()=$name]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="$value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Please provide a small and **reproducible** example - see: [mcve].

Comment: I input a string of non ISO-8859-1 encoding such as "čč". Internal parser escape it to &#269;&#269; and sent to xsl as &#269;&#269; But xslt parse it to &amp;#269;&amp;#269; And finally at page I can see &#269;&#269;, but I want čč.

Comment: Remove your internal parser.  Do not change the characters to entities.  The escaping is something XML uses to internally represent some characters, but as far as all other software is concerned, the XML document contains `č`.

Comment: I can't remove internal parser. Parser represents as library.